# Selecting the Second Maximum Date - Multiple Records

Tags: mysql, max

I need to collate a data set by selecting both the MAX(Date) and the SECONDMAX(DATE) in one result set.

The data source however contains multiple records, which will have a number of different MAX / SECONDMAX dates.

Each record has a unique entity code, which is how I can determine which set of dates belongs to which Entity.

I have written the below query, however I keep getting a message saying

> "Error Code: 1111. Invalid Use of group function.

```
SELECT
   entity_code 'Entity Code',
  (SELECT MAX(visit_date) 
   FROM z_dev.entities_visited A 
   WHERE visit_date < (SELECT MAX(visit_date) 
                       FROM z_dev.entities_visited D 
                       WHERE D.entity_code = A.entity_code) AND
                             C.entity_code = A.entity_code),
  (SELECT MAX(visit_date) 
   FROM z_dev.entities_visited B 
   WHERE visit_date = MAX(visit_date) AND C.entity_code = B.entity_code),
   cycle_end_date
FROM z_dev.entities_visited C
GROUP BY entity_code;
```

SAMPLE DATA

```
entity_code | visit_date | cycle_end_date   
------------+------------+--------------- 
108792      |2016-12-07  |2016-12-11    
108793      |2016-12-08  |2016-12-11    
108795      |2016-12-06  |2016-12-11    
108796      |2016-12-05  |2016-12-11    
108795      |2016-12-13  |2016-12-18    
108792      |2016-12-14  |2016-12-18    
108793      |2016-12-14  |2016-12-18    
108796      |2016-12-16  |2016-12-18
```

Comment: give us some example data http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to get the maximum date and second maximum date per entity_code. for that the following may help you

```
SELECT x.entityCode 'Entity Code',
    x.maxDate,
    (SELECT MAX(visit_date) AS secMaxDate FROM z_dev.entities_visited 
        WHERE entity_code=x.entityCode AND visit_date<x.maxDate),
    cycle_end_date 
FROM 
  (SELECT entity_code AS entityCode,MAX(visit_date) AS maxDate 
    FROM z_dev.entities_visited GROUP BY entity_code) AS X
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I am looking for. What I would like to add to this now is the count of times this entity was visited in the last 28 days.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   entity_code 'Entity Code',
   -- Correlated subquery to get the MAX date
   (SELECT MAX(visit_date)
   FROM entities_visited A
   WHERE A.entity_code = C.entity_code) AS max_visit_date,   
   -- Correlated subquery to get second the MAX date
   (SELECT visit_date
   FROM entities_visited B
   WHERE B.entity_code = C.entity_code
   ORDER BY visit_date DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) AS max_visit_date2
FROM entities_visited C 
GROUP BY entity_code;
```

The query uses correlated subqueries in order to extract the maximum and second maximum `visit_date` per `entity_code`. We can use `OFFSET` with an `ORDER BY` clause in order to get the second maximum date.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de5ef/5)